# Tricky Chinese Poetry Verse About Hotels And Celebrations

Tags: poetry

In a Chinese poem I'm working on, there's a tricky pair of lines I'm having trouble wrapping my head around:

"在走之前迎春日为由的索菲亚酒店
在伟大的欢歌晚宴上，各自献出绝技
拿出月入十分之一的盈余营造一个盛况"

My translation:

"Before going to welcome the spring day at the Sophia Hotel
The guests at the merry banquet all showed off their talents.
offering a tenth of their monthly earnings to fund this spectacular event."

Is my interpretation (a group of people at a hotel banquet fundraising with a talent show) correct?

Answer (score 1):

The part "在走之前迎春日为由的索菲亚酒店" has some grammar mistakes. What is the title of this poem and where was it published?